# Xquery: Find the Makers such that every PC they produce has a price no more than 100

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I'm currently trying to path the conditions "Find the Makers such that every PC they produce has a price no more than 100" and "Find the names of makers that produces at least two PC’s with a speed of 3 or more".  I'm using the data pasted below.

I'm a little lost and would love an example on how to carry this out.

With the Data:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Products>
  <Maker name="A">
    <PC model="1001" price="2114"> 
      <Speed>2.66</Speed>  
      <RAM>1024</RAM>
      <HardDisk>250</HardDisk>
    </PC>
    <PC model="1002" price="995">
      <Speed>2.10</Speed>
      <RAM>512</RAM>
      <HardDisk>250</HardDisk>
    </PC>
    <Laptop model="2004" price="1150">
      <Speed>2.00</Speed>
      <RAM>512</RAM>
      <HardDisk>60</HardDisk>  
      <Screen>13.3</Screen>
    </Laptop>
    <Laptop model="2005" price="2500">
      <Speed>2.16</Speed>
      <RAM>1024</RAM>
      <HardDisk>120</HardDisk>
      <Screen>17.0</Screen>
    </Laptop> 
  </Maker>
  <Maker name="E">
    <PC model="1011" price="959">
      <Speed>l.86</Speed>  
      <RAM>2048</RAM>  
      <HardDisk>160</HardDisk>
    </PC>
    <PC model="1012" price="649">
      <Speed>2.80</Speed>
      <RAM>1024</RAM>
      <HardDisk>160</HardDisk>
    </PC>
    <Laptop model="2001" price="3673">
      <Speed>2.00</Speed>
      <RAM>2048</RAM>
      <HardDisk>240</HardDisk>
      <Screen>20.1</Screen>
    </Laptop>
    <Printer model="3002" price="239">
      <Color>false</Color>
      <Type>laser</Type>
    </Printer>
  </Maker>
  <Maker name="H">
    <Printer model="3006" price="100">
      <Color>true</Color>
      <Type>ink-jet</Type> 
    </Printer>
    <Printer model="3007" price="200">
      <Color>true</Color>
      <Type>laser</Type>
    </Printer>
  </Maker>
</Products>
```

Comment: Any attempts to solve the problem or at least little steps towards a solution? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm a little shaky on my FLWR statements, and I'm really just getting into XQuery, so I'm fairly lost. Really only have a book to guide me as I'm trying to do this on my own.  So far, I've had some ideas on the second question, but am having trouble carrying them out.  I'm used to seeing a restriction on an attribute, like price.  Then I'd be able to do something like: for $x in /Products/Maker/Printer
where $x/@price<100
return <Printer>{$x/Color} 
{$x/Type} </Printer>
However, now I'm looking to put a restriction on Speed, which isn't an attribute, and I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: As for the first question, I've got ideas swimming around in my head but nothing has really come to any sort of useful realization.  I've been watching videos etc. but nothing seems to be giving a really concrete idea on how to approach this

Answer (score 1):

> **Find the Makers such that every PC they produce has a price no more than [1000]**

*I changed 100 to 1000 since there isn't a Maker that makes a PC with a price under 100 in your sample data.*

Another way to read this question is:

*Find the Maker's* (`/Products/Maker`), *that make a PC* (`[PC]`), *that have no PC's with a price greater than 1000* (`[not(PC/@price > 1000)]`).

All put together...

```
/Products/Maker[PC and not(PC/@price > 1000)]
```

Equivalent FLWR statement...

```
for $maker in /Products/Maker
where $maker/PC and not($maker/PC/@price > 1000)
return
    $maker
```

Result (both XPath and FLWR)...

```
<Maker name="E">
    <PC model="1011" price="959">
        <Speed>l.86</Speed>  
        <RAM>2048</RAM>  
        <HardDisk>160</HardDisk>
    </PC>
    <PC model="1012" price="649">
        <Speed>2.80</Speed>
        <RAM>1024</RAM>
        <HardDisk>160</HardDisk>
    </PC>
    <Laptop model="2001" price="3673">
        <Speed>2.00</Speed>
        <RAM>2048</RAM>
        <HardDisk>240</HardDisk>
        <Screen>20.1</Screen>
    </Laptop>
    <Printer model="3002" price="239">
        <Color>false</Color>
        <Type>laser</Type>
    </Printer>
</Maker>
```

---

> **Find the names of makers that produces at least two PC’s with a speed**
>   **of [2] or more**

*I changed 3 to 2 since there isn't a Maker that makes two or more PC's with a speed of 3 or more in your sample data.*

Another way to read this question is:

*Find the names of makers* (`/Products/Maker/@name`) *that produce at least two PC's* (`[count(PC) >= 2]`) *with a speed of 2 or more* (`[Speed >= 2]`).

All put together...

```
/Products/Maker[count(PC[Speed >= 2]) >= 2]/data(@name)
```

Equivalent FLWR statement...

```
for $maker in /Products/Maker
where count($maker/PC[Speed >= 2]) >= 2
return
    data($maker/@name)
```

Result (both XPath and FLWR)...

```
A
```